# Hide the Default Edit button in Wordpress Page and Post types

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor, code-snippets

I a couple of WordPress sites that uses Elementor Page builder. Currently, when I go to Pages, Posts, or custom post types, I see two Edit buttons. One for WordPress editor another for Elementor.

[image: Edit section]

I want to hide the Edit button from all Pages, Posts and custom post types. Then I want to rename the "Edit with Elementor" button to "Edit". What would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: Define "best way".  Like, how do we know which answers to "best way" are right answers and which answers are wrong answers?  Without specific criteria for how to determine right and wrong answers, this question is open to opinions and that's off topic for this site.  The expectation is that you have researched this topic enough to provide a detailed question, with code, so that your question is specific to fixing whatever issue you've encountered with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for **post row actions**: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_row_actions/

Use the ***post_row_actions filter*** to remove desired elements or edit the labels of existing ones.